# Zend Failed opening required in CentOS Plesk server?

Tags: php, zend-framework, centos, plesk, include-path

I get the below error:

```
PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path=':.:/usr/share/zend') in /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/public/index.php on line 18
```

I have a brand new VPS, I thought Plesk would be the way to go but it's a bugger.

I have created a vhost.conf file in my `/var/www/vhosts/domain/conf' dir as follow:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/lovebyte.co.uk/public>
php_admin_value open_basedir none
</Directory>
```

My /etc/php.ini settings:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
include_path = ".:/usr/share/zend"
```

[image]

Anyone got any tips?

Comment: Can you verify that the file `/usr/share/zend/Zend/Application.php` exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=DOMAIN`.

Then I found every occurance of `open_basedir` in the vhost file created in `/var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/conf' folder from running the above command and set them all to`none`.